# Synonymize [c++15] and [c++14]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

The [c++15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b15) tag appears only in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963230/why-does-the-new-c-standard-use-iso-iec-148822015). From the answer to that question, it's clear that the tag isn't needed for other questions. I don't know whether it should just be deleted from the question or made a synonym of [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14).

Comment: I'm marking this [status-declined] now, as there is no use of adding a synonym at the moment (one of the tags is dead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27963230/revisions) wasn't rolled back and the [`Lounge<C++>`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=21249490#21249490) didn't spring into action so the tag [c++15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b15) does no longer exist.

Notice that the tag [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) are already created for future versions of the standard.

Comment: brrr. Creating C++1z is reasonable, but C++17 is a bit premature. Aside from that, iff they both exist, they should be synonyms.

Comment: Yeah, I agree but I don't want to risk the wrath of the c++ gang here...I'm only sharing the facts with all of you ;)